# Django- How to use two UserPassesTestMixin

Tags: python, django

**Using Multiple UserPassesTestMixin Works for other views but not for the `ProfileCreateView`**

There seems to be a logic error which i am not able to figure out!

views.py

```
class CurrentUser(UserPassesTestMixin):
    def test_func(self):
        x = self.request.user.slug
        print (x)
        y = self.kwargs['slug']
        print (y)
        if x == y:
            return True
        else:
            if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
                def get_absolute_url(self):
                    return reverse('profile:view_profile', kwargs={ "slug": self.slug })


class ProfileCreate(CurrentUser, UserPassesTestMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = User
    form_class = ProfileForm
    template_name="profile/profile_new.html"

    def test_func(self):
        x = self.get_object().full_name
        print (x)
        y = ''
        if x == y:
            return True    
        else:
            def get_absolute_url(self):
                return reverse('profile:view_profile', kwargs={ "slug": self.slug })



class ProfileEdit(CurrentUser, UserPassesTestMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = User
    form_class = ProfileForm
    template_name="profile/profile_new.html"

    def test_func(self):
        x = self.get_object().full_name
        #print (x)
        y = ''
        if x != y:
            return True
        else:
            def get_absolute_url(self):
                return reverse('profile:profile_edit', kwargs={ "slug": self.slug })
```

The class `CurrentUser` checks if the user has the permission to edit a profile. A user will only be able to edit the profile if he is the author of the profile. Both the x and y is this class prints different values **x prints the slug value of the loggedin user** whereas **y prints the slug from the url** how can this be true?

The `test_func` in the `ProfileCreate` class checks if the user has already created a profile ie., if the `full_name` is an empty string, then it allows the user to create profile. else redirects to other view.

The `CurrentUser` class works fine for other views such as `ProfileEdit`, etc.,

**Summary!**-- 
loggedin user-  `localhost:8000/username1`

the user will be able to access `localhost:8000/username1/edit/` but not `localhost:8000/username2/edit/`

the user will be able to access `localhost:8000/username1/create/` only if the `full_name` is empty.
If the user is loggedin as username1, then the user should not be able to access `localhost:8000/username2/create/`---- This part of the code does not work. what is the logic error in the code?

Answer (score 1):

You can't have two methods called the same thing. Your `test_func` in ProfileCreate overrides the one in CurrentUser.

Comment: I use the same in `ProfileEdit` Class and works fine.